# Ruby regex seems to not see a `dash`

Tags: ruby, regex

Ruby code:

```
Then /^I verify ([\w\s]+) table contains the following items on the page$/ do | page_table, table |
.......
```

Test:

```
Then I verify Customer-Level Templates table contains the following items on the page
```

When i run the test, it says `Undefined step`. I guess somehow the dash character in `Customer-Level Templates` is being ignored by `([\w\s]+)`. What is the regex so it could grab the whole `Customer-Level Templates` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may add `-` to the character class:

```
/^I verify ([\w\s-]+) table contains the following items on the page$/
```

See a [Rubular test](http://rubular.com/r/18NhnBXcom).

Or make it even more generic by using `.*?` to match any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible:

```
/^I verify (.*?) table contains the following items on the page$/
```

See [another Rubular test](http://rubular.com/r/ExHoEIyaKG).

Note that in Ruby, `^` and `$` match line boundaries. If you need to match the whole *string*, replace `^` with `\A` and `$` with `\z` anchors.

Comment: It's perhaps worth mentioning that the hyphen should be put at the beginning or end of the character class when it is to be matched, as opposed to it being used to define a range. Consider `"a-z"[/[:-^]/] #=> nil`, whereas `"a-z"[/[-:^]/] #=> "-"` and `"a-z"[/[:^-]/] #=> "-"`. This is because `'-' #=> 45`, `':'.ord => 58`, `'^'.ord #=> 94` and `'a'.ord => 97`. Also, one can also get odd results when `"-"` denotes a `nil` range (`r = '^'..':'; r.class #=> Range; r.size #=> nil`): `"a-z"[/[^-:]/] #=> 'a'`. (Wiktor, can you explain this last result?)

Comment: @CarySwoveland: The `/[^-:]/` regex matches `a` in `a-z` string because the [`[^-:]` negated character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) matches any character other than a literal `-` and `:`. In other words, there is no range in this regex since the `-` is at the character class start (the start of the character class is after `[` (if it is positive) or after `[^` (if it is negated).

Comment: Ha! I couldn't see the trees for the forest: I was thinking of the carat as simply a character used to construct my range. It makes more sense that an empty range raises an exception: `SyntaxError: empty range in char class`. Thanks.